# what's the best way to post 30 variables from client side to server?

Tags: php, javascript, http-post, client-server

hey,
i have about 30 variables which are created and modified by user (none of which comes from input, so submitting a form is not really an option), once modification finished a JS function process the variables and spouse to post them to the controller which will then send the to the model.

now, as appears in the title, my question is what is the best way for me to send them?

thnx for time and attention,
Ido

Comment: GET and POST queries usually do the trick. But if any are "lengthy" text, then use POST because most browsers and servers have length limits on URLs.

Comment: Can you show some code of how these variables are stored? I assume the real question here is what's the best way to concatenate 30 variables into a query string for posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern browsers and newer versions of PHP both support JSON, and there are supporting libraries you can use if the browsers you need to support or the PHP version you're stuck with are old.  I'd recommend this as a way of getting data back and forth.

Client side JS:

```
var myobject = {
  userparam: "value",
  anotherThing: "another value",
  something: "etc"
}

var serialized = JSON.stringify(myobject);

// use any AJAX technicque to POST 'serialized' back to the server
```

Then on the server-side:

```
<?php

  $myobject = json_decode( $_POST['serialized'], true );

  $myobject['userparam'] == "value"; // true
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, i'll have a read on JSON, what browsers support it? what can i do if it's not supported?

Comment: The JSON library is not available in older browsers. Use the `json2.js` library by Doughlas Crockford. You should be able to find it easily. For instance here on github: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use `GET` for this unless it's something like a complex search form.

You can `POST` values in JavaScript either by using some form of AJAX or by generating a hidden form and submitting it.

Comment: Mis-read your answer earlier, it's worth asking why you wouldn't use GET though... I can see no reason to not unless the variables are considerably length, or it makes semantic sense in the context of the application.

Comment: Good question. To answer it properly you have to know about the REST protocol (which HTTP is). GET is meant for retrieving data, POST is meant for updating data, in PHP you can use them interchangeably but that's not necessarily a good thing. If you have a page that takes 30 parameters my guess is that it's going to update something (so POST) or it's a super complex search form (so GET). Variable length is a concern too but this is the root of the problem. It also explains why GET typically doesn't have to be very long.

Comment: +1 for clarification. I see what you're getting at and agree with you.

Comment: might i add to the discussion that POST calls the server twice while GET call once, this i fear might extend my wait for a reply.
i do understand your point and because the process is a rather long one anyway i'll try using POST, it's just another thing to take in mind

Answer (score 0):

I would use a POST using an ajax-submitted form.  You can simply create a form with hidden inputs and then use your favorite ajax library to submit the form to the server as a POST request.

Comment: hidden form increases the time takes to respond, it's fine if i've had 10-15 vars but when speaking of something more like 30 it's far to much, especially when considering the site itself isn't the lightest

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are tightly related you can shove them into an array and POST them (use Javascript to construct the array of course). Another alternative would be to name each one of them and POST them separately?

POST array look like this: `arr[]=Hello&arr[]=World`

in PHP you can access it like

```
<?php
arr = $_POST['arr'] // ["Hello", "World"]
?>
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Weigh it up between POST and GET. GET is better if you want to navigate back to the a page with a given set of 'variables'. POST is better if you're submitting a lot of content. However, a POST request is less 'efficient' as a GET request - bear that in mind and only use POST if you really need to.